# How to add another row to jTable

Tags: netbeans, jtable

Before I start, I've read through the current topics on how to do this and the solutions aren't working for me. I've tried table.addRow(...) and that doesn't work. I've tried to add an object but it just resets the table and makes one single row. Here's a basic netbeans pane code :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package components;

import java.awt.event.*;

/**
*
* @author Ethan
*/
public class AccountManager extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form AccountManager
 */
public AccountManager() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Account Manager");

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"Admin", "Admin",  new Integer(1),  new Boolean(true)},
            {"Username", "Password",  new Integer(1),  new Boolean(true)}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Username", "Password", "Account Type", "Active"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jTable1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    jButton1.setText("Add Account");

    class addAccount implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //Action listener for button 1 that adds the row
        }
    }
    jButton1.addActionListener(new addAccount());

    jButton2.setText("Delete Account");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 580, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 220, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addContainerGap(78, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Steel".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AccountManager.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AccountManager.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AccountManager.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AccountManager.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AccountManager().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

So does anyone know how to add a row with netbean's jTable? I would greatly appreciate help on the topic, thanks!

Also, if deleting a row isn't like adding a row in the code, I would appreciate some pointers on how to do that, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is that you are hard coding you entries for you table, you will need some form of database for storing the data. You cannot add entries to your table through a method that will try add coding for specifics.

Best choice is use a embedded database such as SQLite or server database such as MySQL.

There is many different ways to execute such using a database. The best way to add, edit or delete entries to and from a table is through connection and integration with a database. It is simple, easy to use and most effective or efficient method.

coding for connection to a MySQL database:

```
//used to add the entry to database table
       String query = "insert into tableName (col1, col2, col3,col4) values ('data','data','data','data')";
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       //connection
        Connection conn = (Connection)
                //root and username and password for access to the database
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/NameOfDatabase","root","password");
        //create the statement that will be used
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        //executes the query statement
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Must make sure you import you mysql library as well and imports where ever is needed during your code integration throughout.

When you done with adding an entry just refresh your table by calling it up again. Easy way but not the most effective but will help you just out for this section.

Hope this helps

Comment: This isn't necessarily the solution I would have thought of for the specific task, but as coincidence would have it, I was planning on figuring out how to integrate an SQLdatabase later on, so, you are amazing. Thank you! :D

Comment: It's a pleasure, There is a few other ways of doing it, but this way is just the easiest and can make it more advanced just through simple SQL integration. Its a pleasure. Glad to help you!